# async nodemailer sendmail Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, nodemailer

how can I get a 'then', or asynchronously return an API response?
I use fastify, but it doesn't wait for a response if you make a callback inside.
I tried that, but the error: `TypeError: a.then is not a function`

```
         const a = await transporter.sendMail(mainOptions);
            a.then((error, result) => {
                if (error) return error
                reply.send({
                  messageId: result.messageId
                })
            })
```

Comment: Remove the `await`.

Comment: @tkausl ,did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply log `a`:

```js
const a = await transporter.sendMail(mainOptions);
console.log(a)
```

You can also catch the error with a `try/catch`

```js
try {
  const a = await transporter.sendMail(mainOptions);
  console.log(a)
  reply.send({ messageId: result.messageId })
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
}
```

Looks like you are trying to send email with nodemailer. Have you tried to follow the documentation:

```js
transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'sender@example.com',
    to: 'recipient@example.com',
    subject: 'Message',
    text: 'I hope this message gets delivered!'
}, (err, info) => {
    console.log(info.envelope);
    console.log(info.messageId);
});
```

Comment: return undefined

Comment: Your question is not clear enough then. What are you looking for?

Comment: I tried it, but the caps are sent faster. the first code helped!

Answer (score 0):

You should mention the full method/service logic to give you a better solution! however, try this:

- be sure to install nodemailer types `npm i @types/nodemailer`
- you already awaiting transporter to send email, there is no need for `then()` method, try this instead:

```js
try {
 const a = await transporter.sendMail(mainOptions);
 if (a.error) {
   throw a.error;
 }
 reply.send({ messageId: a.result.messageId });
} catch (error) {
 // Handle error
 console.error(error);
}
```